# Add bold text in mail sender text

Tags: php, web

Here is the code:

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";
```

I want to add bold text to: "Name:", "Email:", and "Message"

I have tried using the "< b > name: < /b>" (without space of course), but it doesn´t work. I want the text to be bold when i receive the mail.

Comment: try with the <strong> also check with your header of mail , it should be text/html

Comment: What do you mean with "header of mail"? And i have tried using <strong>, did not work..

Comment: Answer added with code , check and let me know if still it's not working.

Comment: if it's work you can marked the answer accepted so it could be used for others as well.!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

> $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
>   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n\n <strong>Name:</strong> $name \n <strong>Email:</strong> $email_address \n Message \n $message";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need To Set Header Content Type Like This:
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Here is Example ....

```
<?php
$to = 'recivermail@email.com';
$subject = 'Your Subject';
$from = 'sender@email.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Your Title</h1>';
$message .= '<b style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">How Are You?</b>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
?>
```